# prevent submitting if invalid read-only

Tags: html, forms, validation, input

is there a way to prevent form that have invalid but read-only input from submitting without using custom JS code ?

```
<form>
    <input name="number" type="number" value="-1" min="0" readonly>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Nope. If it's `readonly` then the implication is that you, the developer, have control. And it's kinda on you to not provide invalid stuff in the first place :)

Comment: i have an input that depend on the user inputs, i allow for invalid value so that he knows how much he should change his input (instead of just tell him your input is invalid)

Answer (score 0):

I have a select where I check if the user introduce a value from a list with indexOf:

```
if ([1,3,12].indexOf(foo) > -1)
```

Once the user select, the input becomes readonly:

```
document.getElementById("location").readOnly = true;
```

Uppon submission, if location is not readOnly, prevent submit.

*Edited: The other way around I found is empty the input if the user didn't select a value so:

```
var inp = document.getElementById('youInput');
inp.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
   if(postcodes.indexOf(inp) == -1)   {
    inp.value = '';
    alertify.error('Please choose a location from the list.');   
    return false; 
  }
 return true;     
 });
```

Comment: I was trying to do it without js `without using custom JS code`

Comment: sorry, I saw now